# How to Create Sell Order on a marketplace through smart contract?

Tags: tokens, nft, web3.py, binance-smart-chain

I have a txhash of creating sell order for a NFT like this : https://bscscan.com/tx/0x86f091b9ad2eccd625490427ce1636f37319e7ecabfd3dd1f5db8e5023f0ed9a

so I have smart contract: 0xdC8dbca78a5da4f29ca4572DC4734c0048D61C2F and also the ABI

As far as I understand, createSellOrder function of smart contract above was called to make transaction, so I want to do it by web3.py library, but I can't find any createSellOrder function on public contract, so what did I do wrong, how to make it right ?

```
from web3 import Web3

bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'    
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

contract_address = '0xdC8dbca78a5da4f29ca4572DC4734c0048D61C2F'  
contract_address_abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_logic","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"admin_","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"previousAdmin","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"AdminChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"beacon","type":"address"}],"name":"BeaconUpgraded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"implementation","type":"address"}],"name":"Upgraded","type":"event"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"admin_","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"changeAdmin","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"implementation","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"implementation_","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"}],"name":"upgradeTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"upgradeToAndCall","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]')
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_address_abi)

print(dir(contract.functions))
>>>['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hasattr__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_functions', 'abi', 'address', 'admin', 'changeAdmin', 'implementation', 'upgradeTo', 'upgradeToAndCall', 'web3']
```

Comment: It is a proxy contract, it delegates the functionality to another contract 0x3c7e0b528a6ea51a5a9d37cba049bee13dae9b9b, but that contract isn't verified. You should ask the contract creators to provide the ABI if you want to interact with the contract.

Comment: This is amazing thank you so much , can you please tell me where and how did you find this please ?

Comment: By looking at the transaction debug trace, `https://bscscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0x86f091b9ad2eccd625490427ce1636f37319e7ecabfd3dd1f5db8e5023f0ed9a&type=gethtrace2` (top right three dots menu -> Geth Debug Trace 2).

Comment: Oh I understand now, is there any way to find contract ABI of this contract please , many guys make a bot with this contract, I think there must be a way :-?

Comment: Yes, you could reverse engineer the contract, or the mined transactions. Looking at the function it easy to see what parameters are needed `createSellOrder(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price)`: tokenId and price.

Comment: Sorry but I still dont have ABI, so I can't interact with the contract yet :( . Can I interact with a contract without ABI or any way to find ABI please . I'm newbie of this, thank you for your help

Comment: Finally, I did it, thank you so much, you are my life saver <3